# Unwanted characters in regular expressions python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, python-requests

So, I have a site that has an XML string, and I'd like my program to return a list of strings that appear between two strings. Here's my code:

```
 response = requests.get(url)


 artists=re.findall(re.escape('<name>')+'(.*?)'+re.escape('</name>'),str(response.content))
 print(artists)
```

This returns a list of strings. The problem is, some strings have unwanted characters in them. For example, one of the strings in the list is "Somethin\\' \\'Bout A Truck" and I'd like it to be 'Somethin' 'Bout A Truck'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `have a site that has an XML string,`  What about bs4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the beautiful soup(bs4) will solve this problem and it will also  support for higher version of python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

Those escapes (single backslashes, each displayed as `\\`) may be "unwanted" from your viewpoint but they're no doubt "present" in the response you received.  So if characters are present but unwanted, you can **remove** them, e.g using in lieu of `str(response.content)`

```
str(response.content).replace('\\'. '')
```

if what you actually want to do is remove all such escapes (if you want to do something different than that you'd better explain what it is:-).

`BeautifulSoup4` as recommended in the accepted answer, though a nice package indeed, does **not** wantonly remove characters present in the input -- it can't read your mind, so it can't know what's "unwanted" to you.  E.g:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> s = '<name>Somethin\\\' \\\'Bout A Truck</name>'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> print(soup)
<name>Somethin\' \'Bout A Truck</name>
>>>
```

As you see, the escapes (backslashes) are still there before the single-quotes.